# DataTables - Requested unknown parameter

Tags: javascript, java, spring, datatables

This is my first time when I try to use DataTables and I don't understand what I do wrong.

This is DataTables:

```
var table = $('#kt_table_1');
table.DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searchDelay: 500,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        "url": "http://localhost:8081/services/test",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    order: [[2, "desc"], [0, "desc"], [6, "asc"]],
    columns: [
        {data: "externalId"},
        {data: "shippingName"},
        {data: "date"},
        {data: "trackingNumber"},
        {data: "shippingCost"},
        {data: "shippingDetails"},
        {data: "status"}
    ]
});
```

This is html:

```
<table id="kt_table_1"></table>
```

And this is what I return from Spring App:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> getOrders(){

    String jsonResponse =
            "{" +
                "\"draw\": 1, " +
                "\"recordsTotal\": 1, " +
                "\"recordsFiltered\": 1, " +
                "\"data\": [ " +
                    "[" +
                        "{" +
                            "\"externalId\": \"11111\", " +
                            "\"shippingName\": \"Foo\", " +
                            "\"date\": \"2019-10-22\", " +
                            "\"trackingNumber\": \"TR123123\", " +
                            "\"shippingCost\": \"2.35\", " +
                            "\"shippingDetails\": \"Country-Name\", " +
                            "\"status\": \"1\"" +
                        "}" +
                    "]" +
                "]" +
            "}";

    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).body(jsonResponse);

}
```

But when I enter on page with table I get an alert with message:

```
DataTables warning: table id=kt_table_1 - Requested unknown parameter 'externalId' for row 0, column 0. 
For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`
```

If I use Postman to do a POST to `http://localhost:8081/services/test` I get the json on page.

Why I get `unknown parameter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using POST method to get informations? I think you should use just simple GET.

For your datatable you need list of objects. In your controller you have list of lists of objects.

Comment: I use `post` because in documentation of datatables I don't find that information, so I thought `post` is good. `list of lists of objects` - that was the problem. Thank you!